# Use reflection to reset input calibration internal api (allwinner)

Tags: java, android, reflection

I try to modify an app to compile without compile with the android firmware
the only internal methods that call are the following

```
//Imports
    import android.os.ServiceManager;
    import android.view.IWindowManager;
//Internal Api Calls
IWindowManager mWindowManager   = 
IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));                          
mWindowManager.resetInputCalibration();
```

Is posible to achive this via java reflection ??